# What justice and legislative system reforms have been proposed that account for the absence of free will?

Tags: united-states, law, crime, legislation

From what I understand, psychology plays a large role in our criminal justice systems- especially in the United States. Psychologists evaluate police officers who go on to arrest people who are evaluated by psychologists. This makes sense, because we wouldn’t want to call an officer to our home if he has a brain tumor that gives him murderous tendencies. We may also have more sympathy towards a murderer if we learn of some sort of irregularity in their mind.

These are some of the arguments [Sam Harris brings up in his book *Free Will*](https://samharris.org/the-illusion-of-free-will/), and while many [claim he is wrong](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4887467/#!po=0.384615), there’s not much else they can say. [Deniers of free will propagate *corrective chastisement* for “criminals” rather than *punishment*](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/one-among-many/201802/the-dangerous-doctrine-free-will). I would assume most neuroscientists and psychologists agree with Harris.

For example, in recent years there has been a shift in opinion towards people who are addicted to drugs, because many psychologists have recognized that *addiction is a disease* and [drug addicts do not have free will](https://www.drugabuse.gov/about-nida/noras-blog/2015/06/addiction-disease-free-will). So instead of throwing addicts into cages, it’s been proposed that they get treatment and help. It actually makes a lot of sense if you think about it. Something *caused* a heroin addict to use heroin (prescription pills, peer pressure, etc) which had an *evil effect*, so now we need another *cause* (treatment) to help them obtain a *good effect*.

^^^That is just an example of how legislation has changed to account for an absence of free will. My question is not about drug rehabilitation because I don’t believe drugs should be illegal.

**What justice and legislative system reforms have been proposed that account for the *complete* absence of free will?**

Comment: This question is based on assumptions which are not made explicit as they are not referenced. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you are ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you need help, you can view our [ask] page. Thanks

Comment: Is this the appropriate site for this question? Would't be better philosophy.se / politics.se?

Comment: Contra to your assertion there is much more they can say: https://aphilosopherstake.com/2012/07/29/free-will-why-sam-harris-needs-to-read-more-philosophy/ or https://www.richardcarrier.info/archives/13814 etc.

Comment: @Fizz Thanks for the article about [measuring free will](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4887467/#!po=0.384615). It’s very interesting. When I get time to ask questions about it, I’ll let you know. Well, that’s what I *want* to do.

Comment: Just a thought: if there is absolutely no free will, then anything we do to punish people is already predestined. However, I realize you're talking about less free will, and not a COMPLETE absence of free will.

Comment: Downvoted because the question is based on a false premise.  It's like asking what justice and legislative system reforms have been proposed that account for the absence of gravity?  (And WRT drug addicts, the ill effects are almost all due to the government's decision - free will, you know? - to make drug use illegal.)

Comment: The original question (as I answered) made a strong statement (inspired from Harris) that *all* people (and thus all criminals) completely lack free will. The NIDA stuff about addicts is obviously much more nuanced, so I feel it's not quite appropriate to mix the topics.

Comment: @Fizz My question is about a complete lack of free will for everyone. I only added the NIDA stuff as an example of how legislative decisions are already being influenced by the free will debate. Maybe I should clarify my question. You’re answer is good, but I feel like it’s mostly an attempt to deny the premise, rather than answer the question.

Comment: @barrycarter This question is about a complete absence of free will. My example about drug addiction is just an example. Yes, the punishments are already predetermined, but that doesn’t mean the punishments cannot change in the future. Of course, whether they change in the future is also predetermined, but if they are predetermined to change- it will be be*cause* we *caused* it to change. We can’t have an effect without a cause.

Comment: @Joshua If the entire universe is predetermined, there is really no cause and effect. Things just happen in whatever predestined way they were going to happen anyway.

Comment: @barrycarter Right, but from our perspective, there is cause and effect- so nothing will happen unless we cause it. If the government is slaughtering their citizens and everyone just says “If only our dictator would use his free will and do better”, it’s never going to happen. Action is required for an effect, and you don’t know whether your actions could help change the world towards the predetermined goodness it’s meant to become, so you might as well try. What else is there to do anyway? “Vanity of vanities, saith the Preacher, vanity of vanities; all is vanity.” Ecclesiastes 1:2

Comment: You said "nothing will happen unless we cause it". But that doesn't make sense. If there is no free will, we can't cause anything to happen. We have no choice. Any action we take is already predetermined. I don't know whether my actions will change the world, but I have no choice in the matter.

Comment: @barrycarter If determinism is true, then the homeless man you saw when you were 12 would be one of the underlying causes for why you now volunteer at a homeless shelter and saved Bob’s life. It doesn’t matter if *you* caused it or if an asteroid 5 billion years ago caused it- all that matters is Bob is alive and he’s about to cure cancer.

Comment: So you didn’t just wake up one day and magically make thoughts appear in your brain that said “You should volunteer at a homeless shelter”. Something *caused* that decision, or the standard interpretation of QM is true and the thought randomly popped in your head through some sort of mental quantum fluctuation. Either way, there can be no free will.

Comment: @jamesqf:  I'll agree to the conclusion, but think the government choice and collective support of government are not the best argument for Free Will.  In both examples for the disease argument, they offer choices that were.  In the former, through no fault of his own, he becomes addicted by legal means.  He knows that he is craving more of a substance that he does not have and has options to address the problem.  He could go to some addiction counseling service or rehab OR he could seek a quick fix which he knows attaches problems.+

Comment: +Choice still exists, but no one said all choices are of equal difficulty or equally beneficial.  I would say so long as you have not made the choice to remove all agency of personal free will (suicide would be the best example), then the ability to choose an action remains than Free Will remains.  It is only after the choice to terminate all agency of choice is fully executed that I suggest that you exist in a material state as a being with out choice.

Comment: @hszmv: My point (besides the one about most of the bad effects of addiction being due to the government's making drugs illegal) is that the addict has choices.  It was a choice to start using the drug in the first place.  It's a choice to keep on using it, rather than resist the cravings.  There are people who choose not to keep using: consider that it's widely said that tobacco is more addictive than heroin, yet millions of people have chosen to quit smoking.

Comment: @jamesqf:  Which I am in total agreement, I just think in deference to the argument "Does Free Will exist" that the argument that there there is a situation that can be resolved in more than one option, and that the consequences of that option are accepted by his choice.  I am not making arguement to the consequences being just or invalidating their existence because of the source they derive from.  Only that the individual knew the consequences, decided they were worth the risk, and is therefor responsible if they occur.

Comment: @jamesqf:  I think you might be right, but I think the threat of heroin is the addiction is more immediate to first use (There is risk for addiction to occur on first use of heroin, where as cigarettes more than one use to achieve the same level).  Though I'm not at all knowledgeable on Drugs beyond Breaking Bad is an awesome show that explores almost every aspect about the effects of drugs on society at large.

Comment: @hszmv: We're wandering rather far from my point, which is that it's impossible to demonstrate that free will does not exist. (Or that it does, because any action can be said to be predetermined after the fact.) So it's pointless to ask a question about it: doubly so, because any changes would be predetermined anyway :-)

Answer (score 5):

Since Harris apparently failed to make his own point on the law implications of his viewpoint on free will, I'll have to quote that from one of his main critics, [Dennett](https://www.rifp.it/ojs/index.php/rifp/article/download/rifp.2017.0018/777):

> Harris, like the other scientists who have recently mounted a campaign to convince the world that free will is an illusion, has a laudable motive: to launder the ancient stain of Sin and Guilt out of our culture, and abolish the cruel and all too usual punishments that we zestfully mete out to the Guilty. As they point out, our zealous search for “justice” is often little more than our instinctual yearning for retaliation dressed up to look respectable. The result, especially in the United States, is a barbaric system of imprisonment – to say nothing of capital punishment – that should make all citizens ashamed. By all means, let’s join hands and reform the legal system, reduce its excesses and restore a measure of dignity – and freedom! – to those whom the state must punish. But the idea that all punishment is, in the end, unjustifiable and should be abolished because nobody is ever really responsible, because nobody has “real” free will is not only not supported by science or philosophical argument; it is blind to the chilling lessons of the not so distant past. Do we want to medicalize all violators of the laws, giving them indefinitely large amounts of involuntary “therapy” in “asylums” (the poor dears, they aren’t responsible, but for the good of the society we have to institutionalize them)? I hope not. But then we need to recognize the powerful (consequentialist) arguments for maintaining a system of punishment (and reward). Punishment can be fair, punishment can be justified, and in fact, our societies could not manage without it.
>
> This discussion of punishment versus medicalization may seem irrelevant to Harris’s book, and an unfair criticism, since he himself barely alludes to it, and offers no analysis of its possible justification, but that is a problem for him. He blandly concedes we will – and should – go on holding some people responsible but then neglects to say what that involves. Punishment and reward? If not, what does he mean? If so, how does he propose to regulate and justify it? I submit that if he had attempted to address these questions he would have ended up with something like this: Those eligible for punishment and reward are those with the general abilities to respond to reasons (warnings, threats, promises) rationally. Real differences in these abilities are empirically discernible, explicable, and morally relevant. Such abilities can arise and persist in a deterministic world, and they are the basis for a justifiable policy of reward and punishment, which brings society many benefits – indeed makes society possible. (Those who lack one or an-other of the abilities that constitute this moral competence are often said, by everyday folk, to lack free will, and this fact is the heart of compatibilism.)
>
> If you think that the fact that incompatibilist free will is an illusion demonstrates that no punishment can ever be truly deserved, think again. It may help to consider all these issues in the context of a simpler phenomenon: sports. In basketball there is the distinction between ordinary fouls and flagrant fouls, and in soccer there is the distinction between yellow cards and red cards, to list just two examples. Are these distinctions fair? Justified? Should Harris be encouraged to argue that there is no real difference between the dirty player and the rest (and besides, the dirty player isn’t responsible for being a dirty player; just look at his upbringing!)? Everybody who plays games must recognize that games without strictly enforced rules are not worth playing, and the rules that work best do not make allowances for differences in heritage, training, or innate skill. So it is in society generally: we are all considered equal under the law, presumed to be responsible until and unless we prove to have some definite defect or infirmity that robs us of our free will, as ordinarily understood.

And what Dennett talks about with indefinite treatement is more real than you might know; various US states have such statues of indefinte civil confinement on the books; [typically for sex offenders](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2013/sep/26/civil-commitment-sex-offenders). And the detention of these [hardly differs](https://www.texasobserver.org/a-prison-by-any-other-name/) from [life] [im]prison[ment].

So basically if were to posit that law would dispense with any notion of responsibility (and thus perhaps even with criminal law altogether), a generalized "civil" containment model as hinted by Dennett is not too unreasonable of an inference.

And Harris (or Dennett) is hardly the first guy to [talk of this](https://scholarworks.uvm.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.ro/&httpsredir=1&article=1099&context=hcoltheses):

> Derk Pereboom has argued for a position called
>   hard incompatibilism, which asserts that we are simply not the sort of creatures who can
>   be morally responsible for our actions. [...]   But if criminals cannot be held morally responsible for their actions, then there is
>   a serious problem with [the current justice] practices. Since criminals do not deserve to be punished, it
>   would appear as though punishing them would be unjustified. I explain that in order to
>   have properly justified crime control practices, we need to either form a different
>   conception of moral responsibility, or we need to change our current crime control
>   practices. In other words, we need to be revisionists about either moral responsibility or
>   about punishment. [Manuel Vargas](http://vargasphilosophy.com/publication.htm) has argued that we ought to do the former, and
>   Pereboom has argued that we ought to do the latter.
>   Vargas suggests that we reconceptualize moral responsibility, but maintain our
>   responsibility-characteristic practices for pragmatic reasons. [Pereboom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derk_Pereboom#Free_will), on the other
>   hand, suggests that we stop holding people morally responsible
>   altogether and instead
>   revise our system of criminal law to account for this change. [...]
>
> Pereboom's
>   own suggestion for a system of crime control [is] the incapacitation approach. This model
>   suggests that we justify incapacitating criminals by invoking the right to protect ourselves
>   as an analogy to quarantine.

---

A [slightly more elaborate/concrete proposal](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.0915161107), by a biologist (Cashmore, 2010):

> Progress in understanding the chemical basis of behavior will make it increasingly untenable to retain a belief in the concept of free will. To retain any degree of reality, the criminal justice system will need to adjust accordingly. However, to retain a degree of orderliness in society it will still be necessary to incarcerate individuals found guilty of certain criminal acts. This is rationalized in various ways including the following: To a), protect society; b), protect the offending individuals from society; c), provide such individuals with appropriate psychiatric help; d), act as a deterrent (the act of incarceration and the presence of a criminal code forming part of the environment); and e), alleviate the pain of the victim. The proposal is a pragmatic one, based on the belief that the welfare of society at large is more important than the welfare of the individual offender.
>
> One might ask: How does this proposal differ from the present system? Whereas in some ways, not significantly; in other ways it differs fundamentally. The primary difference would be the elimination of the illogical concept that individuals are in control of their behavior in a manner that is something other than a reflection of their genetic makeup and their environmental history. Furthermore, psychiatrists and other experts on human behavior should be eliminated from the initial judicial proceedings—the role of the jury would be to simply determine whether or not the defendant was guilty of committing the crime; the mental state of the defendant would play no part in this decision. However, if a defendant were found guilty, then a court-appointed panel of experts would play a role in advising on matters of punishment and treatment. This is a system that would hopefully minimize the retributive aspect of criminal law; concerns about this aspect of law, which have probably been around since laws were first introduced, include those expressed by Wootton (33), Menninger (36), and, more recently, Greene and Cohen (37). Also I note that I am not the first to propose that psychiatrists should be excluded from the initial court proceedings; Glueck (38) and Menninger (36), for example, who both had substantially more expertise than I have in this field, long ago made similar suggestions.

According to this view, juries should only establish external facts, leaving the inner working of the defendant entirely to the punishment/treatment phase, which is to be handled by experts.

It's interesting to note in connection to these proposals that a [2012 controlled experiment](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22904010) published in the high-impact *Science* journal,  found that when US judges are presented with a "biomechanism" for psychopathy (in this case a combined genetic and neurological explanation: low MAOA activity and atypical amygdala function) they tend to give a somewhat shorter prison sentence (from 13.93 years to 12.83 years). Note that his was not a forgone conclusion (that the sentence would be shorter), as the likelihood of recidivism is presumably higher under a biological determinant, and this has to be taken into account by US judges upon sentencing (this is elaborated in the introduction of the paper). Nevertheless, the judges saw on average the biomechanism as more mitigating than aggravating.

Comment: Wondering if the downvote because the question is on wrong site or because the answer is bad.

Comment: @rus9384: if you think the question is good, why don't you upvote it? I assume it is you who downvoted my answer. I didn't upvote the question because it showed a fair bit of jumping to conclusions / insufficient research.

Comment: I'm not sure the question is on appropriate site. And yes, your reason also is good enough. That's a ridiculous claim to accuse me being a downvoter when I myself am merely interested in the reason for the downvote. Unfortunately, some downvoters do not comment why they did. That sucks. But I didn't downvote. Not sure I can judge this.

Comment: So what are the suggested reforms?

Comment: Nobody is advocating “indefinite treatment”, because the goal is not to lock people in cages; the goal is to help them, and if they cannot be helped, then we must do *something* with them because they are a danger to society. Remember, everyone loved Lassie, but when she got rabies, there was nothing else they could do. It’s sad, but until there’s a cure for being a serial killer, what else can we do? Of course, we also don’t want government psychologists “recommending” indefinite treatment, or another MK Ultra. That’s why I think this question is important.

Comment: A useful answer, that lacks any survey of implementations based on the errors it critiques.  That is, if somebody asked about racist-by-design legal systems, a useful refutation of racism still wouldn't supply a list of racist legal systems.

Comment: @agc: because there aren't any implementations. These are just philosophers arguing. Also, Joshua edited the question to add the stuff about adicts after I answered it as it was originally posed, which was about crimes in the very general.

Answer (score 3):

If criminals lack free will, that's tantamount to considering them as deterministic computers running either:

1. self-modifying code
2. certain unchangeable programs the behavior of which depends on the data input and stored.
3. fixed programs that never learn.

Assuming all three of these exist, it might be difficult to tell them apart.  It might be that punitive prisons as we know them have evolved as a *one-size fits all* means of modifying the code where possible, or replacing the crimey old data with lawful new data, or preventing those fixed programs from outputting crime in the world.

But if we allow that criminals lack free will, perhaps that lack applies to society as a whole, and its governments too, in which case governments can hardly be blamed when they naturally do wrong.  How well punitive prisons adapt to changing conditions is another story, but perhaps prisons too have no choice.

So if the present system already meets the operational and functional specs of the proposed reforms, then reform would mostly be superfluous.  The only change needed would be re-labeling, or translation.

---

(Note:  I am not a skeptic of free-will or prison reform.)

Comment: You are not wrong, but you haven't actually answered the question: "What justice and legislative system reforms have **been proposed**?"

Comment: This is an interesting answer. I do believe that governments are predetermined and lack free will, and when they get out of control like a rabid dog, we need to put them down. I think your answer is very close to what I’m looking for, except maybe you could add some more details to what neuroscientists and psychologists have proposed we do to solve our prison problems.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to understand the basis of "punishment" or "corrective chastisement" in the justice system.  We generally divide the reasons into several categories:

1. Incapacitation.  This means that the offender can no longer commit offenses as the response prevents them.  For example, we might imprison the offender to prevent murders and thefts on the general population.
2. Retribution.  This is the state punishing offenders so that the victims don't.
3. Deterrence.  If people know that they will be punished, they may not commit the crime in the first place.
4. Rehabilitation.  This is where the offender receives training or other resources to help the offender stop engaging in criminal behavior.
5. Reparation.  This is where the offender compensates the victims.

I have put these in rough order of effectiveness of typical punishments, like imprisonment.  Imprisonment separates the offender from the general populace, thereby preventing crimes for the period of the prison term.  Imprisonment serves as a punishment, so victims don't feel the need to engage in their own retribution.  Imprisonment has limited deterrence effect, as most criminals do not expect to get caught.  Imprisonment offers rehabilitation services, but they have limited effectiveness.  Imprisonment offers no reparation to the victims.

Now, let's compare to outpatient treatment.  This doesn't incapacitate the offender, who can continue to commit offenses.  It doesn't substitute for retribution by the victims.  It's not a deterrent.  It doesn't offer reparations.  It may be slightly more effective at rehabilitation.

Imprisonment is therefore better at three of the categories and essentially the same at reparations.  It's only at rehabilitation that it is possibly superior at all.  And the evidence on that is mixed.

The problem is that rehabilitation only works with the assistance of the offender, and most offenders do not want to stop offending.  This is especially true of drug addicts.  If unwilling people go to Narcotics Anonymous, they're more likely to use it to acquire or sell drugs than to quit.  If we assume that they have no free will, this only gets worse.  Because rehabilitation and deterrence assume free will.

Incapacitation does not require free will.  It works even if the offender resists.

Retribution assumes that the victims have free will but doesn't care about the offenders.

Reparations typically fail because most offenders lack the resources to compensate their victims.  For example, most drug addicts engage in activities like theft in order to make money to buy drugs.  And of course, they spend that money immediately.

From this perspective, it should be clear that the current system, based on imprisonment, already works with a lack of free will on the part of offenders.  It works by incapacitating the offender for a period of time.  And realize, incapacitation is not punitive.  We don't incapacitate offenders to punish them but to directly prevent them from offending.  The method of incapacitation may also punish, but the primary purpose is still incapacitation under most theories of jurisprudence.

We can do a similar comparison with capital punishment.  It is slightly more effective at the first three categories and useless at the last two.  It is also more expensive.  So we reserve it for particularly serious crimes (and still may use it inefficiently).  And except for deterrence, its effectiveness is not reliant on free will.

Specifically looking at drug addiction, realize that we have no good solutions.  Rehabilitation programs are mostly ineffective, as most addicts don't want to quit.  Imprisonment is rather expensive for something that is itself mostly harmful to the offender.  But it may prevent the adoption of other behaviors that are more harmful.  Legalization combined with free rehabilitation paid out of taxes on the legalized product may be cheaper to the rest of society.  But it still leaves problems with people who can't get legal work to pay for their drug habits, as junkies do not make the best employees.

**TL;DR**:  the current system is one that does not require free will from offenders to be effective.  Meanwhile, the proposed alternatives rely on offenders' support (i.e. free will).  This seems largely because people get overly hung up on punishment and don't consider effectiveness.

Comment: Thanks I like this answer. So are you saying most of our current justice system doesn’t require free will, and actually attempts to function in a deterministic manner anyway? Locking murderers up will have the effect of stopping the murders, it will have the effect of satisfying the victim’s family, and it hopefully has the effect of deterrence- which will cause people to second-guess if they should follow through with the murder. Am I interpreting this correctly? Also, I agree drugs should be legalized. Whatever *effect* it was meant to have- it has failed tremendously.

Comment: You are not wrong, but you haven't actually answered the question: "What justice and legislative system reforms have **been proposed**?"

Answer (score 2):

I can not prove a negative, but I could not find any evidence that the arguments made by Sam Harris prompted any politician anywhere in the world to propose any grand-scale justice system reform.

One reason is that there is little political pressure to do such a reform.

Another is that the idea that convicted criminals should be reformed instead of harmed is already recognized in political theory. The political theory behind legal punishment is that [punishment serves 5 different purposes](http://open.lib.umn.edu/criminallaw/chapter/1-5-the-purposes-of-punishment/):

1. **Incapacitation**: Prevent the criminals from committing other crimes by removing them from society and/or take a way the resources to commit further crimes.
2. **Rehabilitation**: Reform the criminals, so they no longer want to commit crimes.
3. **Deterrence**: Convince other potential criminals that the crimes they consider committing are not worth the risk of punishment.
4. **Retribution**: Give the victims and the public the satisfaction that justice was served.
5. **Restitution**: Repair the damage the criminal caused (for example, by having them pay a fine to the victim)

None of these assume that criminals have free will. 1-3 assume that there is a deterministic cause->effect relationship between imprisoning criminals and reduced crime rates. 4 and 5 is about satisfying a psychological and material need of the victim and the society as a whole.

Different justice system around the world put different priority on these purposes.

- Some countries focus on retribution and deterrence, so they try to make prison sentences as uncomfortable as their human rights standards permit.
- Some focus on incapacitation, which means they sentence people to very long prison sentences and even restrict the rights of convicts after they served their sentence.
- Some focus on restitution, which means they avoid prison sentences and instead sentence criminals to pay reparations to the victims, pay fines to the government or perform work for the benefit of society.
- Some focus on rehabilitation, which means prisons focus on educational programs and therapy.

Comment: I think your assessment that criminal law today has nothing to do with a notion of free will is far from being universally accepted  "The criminal law is based on the capacity of the individual to
make free choices and the assumption that virtually all of our
behavior virtually all of the time is a result of free choice. This
may or may not be a description of reality. But the criminal law
as we know it cannot function without the hallmarks of
responsibility, blame, and punishment as the working premises
for most behavior."

Comment: That's quoted in http://www.antoniocasella.eu/dnlaw/Mammarella_2016.pdf from PETER W. Low, BLACK LETTER OUTLINES: CRIMINAL LAW 199 (3d ed. 2007), which looks like a pretty standard textbook.

Comment: Almost all the people who argue for some kind of "neuro" revolution of criminal law take most issue with retribution... and the latter features prominently in US system (to which that textbook is dedicated.)

Comment: And from the same paper "the
Supreme Court has noted, "a deterministic view of human conduct . .. is
inconsistent with the underlying precepts of our criminal justice system."" United States v. Grayson, 438 U.S. 41, 52 (1978).

Comment: @Fizz Why didn’t you add any of this to your answer? It’s very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fairly new field of study called [**neurolaw**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurolaw) and it seeks to answer this question. Most neuroscientists have known for decades that it is impossible for our *will* to be *free*.

From Wikipedia:

> Decisions became increasingly based on the M’Naghten Rules, which asserted that unless one was able to prove that a mental illness kept him or her from knowing that the act was wrong, or knowing the disposition of the criminal act, one would not be able to be tried as mentally handicapped. **Contemporary research conducted on the prefrontal cortex has criticized this standpoint because it considers impaired volition as a factor.**
>
> **Many courts are now considering "irresistible impulse" as legitimate grounds for mental illness.** One of the factors neuroscience has added to the insanity defense is the claim that **the brain “made someone do it.”**
>
> In these cases, the argument is based on an understanding that **decisions are made before the person is able to consciously realize what is happening**. More research on control and inhibition mechanisms will allow further modifications to the insanity defense.

While neuroscience and psychology can help determine appropriate measures to correct behavior, the fact that most people overwhelmingly believe in *free will* poses some dangerous consequences. [Advertisers and propagandist already know that free will does not exist](https://newintrigue.com/2015/09/09/on-advertising-and-the-loss-of-free-will/), and they actively use that to their advantage.

Several [governments and militaries](https://royalsociety.org/topics-policy/projects/brain-waves/conflict-security/) have also been interested in neuroscience for decades. While MK Ultra may have failed to produce results (according to *them*, and probably because they got caught), [modern techniques are definitely worrisome](https://thebulletin.org/2017/10/neuroscience-and-the-new-weapons-of-the-mind/).

So it appears to be an ongoing debate, and while most people probably think it’s all nonsense because they’re certain they control their destiny- those who know the scientific facts are already exploiting that.

I would argue that there was one other historical figure who talked about this frequently. He spoke of “age-enduring chastisement” that is best left to God, the importance of never judging others, the radical idea of forgiving others unconditionally, and one of his last recorded words were:

> ”Then said Jesus, Father, forgive them; **for they know not what they do**.” -Luke 23:34